# following book examples using Unicode Character Set

Tags: windows

I'm reading a book called "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 9.0c: A Shader Approach" and I was following the codes there but the application used  Multi-Byte Character Set and I read from somewhere that it's not a good practice to use that and im having error when creating a window. here is the code that im having error.

```
mhMainWnd = CreateWindow(L"D3DWndClassName", mMainWndCaption.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - width/2, 
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - height/2,
            R.right, R.bottom, 0, 0, mhAppInst, 0);
```

then the eror is:

```
error C2664: 'CreateWindowExW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [16]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

hope someone can help me

Comment: Multi-byte strings are an artifact from the previous century.  Just use the Ansi functions explicitly to keep the sample code from the book working, append an A to the function name.  CreateWindowA in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you heard about the preferability of Unicode over the ANSI/MBCS is entirely correct. All new Windows code should be written to work with Unicode. In order to make this happen, you have to ensure two things:

1. **Both the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` symbols need to be defined globally** to ensure that the Unicode versions of the API functions are called, even if you forget the `W` suffix.

   You can either do this at the top of your precompiled header

   ```
   #define UNICODE
   #define _UNICODE
   ```

   or in your project's Properties window within Visual Studio. Simply add both of the values to the list.
2. **All of your strings (both literals and otherwise) need to be Unicode strings.**

   With literals, you accomplish this by prefixing them with L, just as you've done in the example: `L"D3DWndClassName"`

   With strings that are allocated at runtime, you need to use the `wchar_t` type. Since you're using C++, you should obviously be using a string class rather than raw character arrays like you would in C. So you need to use a string class that treats the characters in the string as `wchar_t`. This would either be `std::wstring` or MFC/ATL/WTL's `CStringW` class.

It looks like you've got most of this down already. The culprit is `mMainWndCaption.c_str()`. You are using `std::string` (which returns a nul-terminated array of `char`s) instead of `std::wstring` (which returns a nul-terminated array of `wchar_t`s).

Comment: @rfv Project Settings -> Configuration -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions

Comment: Use General + Character Set instead.  He already has it set correctly or he wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Either change your project to ANSI or MBCS rather than UNICODE, then change

```
L"D3DWndClassName"
```

to

```
"D3DWndClassName"
```

or, leave your project properties as UNICODE but use a UNICODE string of your window caption - so

```
CString szCaption(mMainWndCaption.c_str());   // CString is actually CStringW in UNICODE build

mhMainWnd = CreateWindow(L"D3DWndClassName", szCaption, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - width/2, 
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - height/2,
            R.right, R.bottom, 0, 0, mhAppInst, 0);
```

Comment: Targeting the ANSI/MBCS is not a viable option unless you own a time machine. And there's no reason to start using the MFC CString class if he's not already using MFC. The `c_str` method is part of the `std::string` class, so just use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: thx for your answers. i will use the std::wstring coz im havign trouble using the CSString because of the include <atlstr.h>

Comment: @CodyGray - good point, sorry, still got my head stuck in MFC from work :-(